# Codeigniter page routing not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 3 and am having problems getting the router to work in my development environment. Relevant portions of files:

site/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

site/application/config/routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'auth/login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1';
```

site/application/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/~me/site/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

site/application/controllers/Page.php

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Page extends CI_Controller {
public function view($page = 'about')
{
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        redirect('auth/login');
    }
    if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/page/'.$page.'.php')) {
        show_404();
    }
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('page/'.$page);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Results:

```
localhost/~me/site takes me to login as expected (routes.php is being called)
localhost/~me/site/index.php/page/view/about works (basic logic works)
localhost/~me/site/index.php/page/about works ($route['page/(:any)'] works)
```

But, what I want to use is: localhost/~me/site/page/about which gives:

```
The requested URL /index.php/page/about was not found on this server
```

I get the same error with localhost/~me/site/page/view/about

So it seems as if routes.php is only reached if I either:
a) call out index.php explicitly, or
b) call the route without any extension

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I've tried this file config before, but I'll try again with my current configuration when my server is back up. Some edit I made yesterday apparently messed up my access after a shutdown/restart (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239817/safari-cant-open-the-page-localhost-me)

Comment: I've done a complete re-install of the OS (I was experiencing other anomalies as well). The server seems to be running fine again but I still experience the same results. The above recommended .htaccess file only resulted in changing the reference in the error message to /index.php rather than /index.php/page/about. 
At this point, I am wondering if it might be an issue with OS X Yosemite and/or Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put **AllowOverride All** directive to your Apache config file or virtual host config file?