# Safari can't open the page "localhost/~me"

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

It was working fine yesterday, but this morning I cannot get to my personal subdirectories. I can get to localhost and localhost/~kvaughn fine, but localhost/~kvaughn/ returns the following format regardless of which subdirectory I choose. 
[image: Can't connect to the server screenshot]

I did make some edits to kvaughn.conf yesterday, but it was still working fine after running apachectl restart.

```
<Directory "/Users/me/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</Directory>
```

BTW: When I first started this morning, I could not even reach localhost/~kvaughn, but I resolved that issue by removing FollowSymLinks from kvaughn.conf and restarting apachectl. But if that was the issue, why did the site continue to work yesterday after adding it?

Comment: This seems like it could be an environmental issue, which I don't know if SO would be able to resolve that effectively. But I guess you did answer the first part of: is the webserver service running?

Comment: It was working fine yesterday

Comment: That was why my first guess was the service wasn't running; if you didn't have the service on autostart and you restarted your desktop environment, the service wouldn't be running unless you started it manually.